# Setup a proxy server in .env file ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, proxy

I'm trying to set up an environment variable, but it's not working, my server only connects with I define `"proxy":"http://localhost:3001"` in package.json, I would like to do this:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "docapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^3.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "canvas": "^2.8.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "face-api.js": "^0.22.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-face": "^0.1.6",
    "react-fade-in": "^2.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-webcam": "^6.0.0",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "rules": {
      "eqeqeq": 0
    },
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "${PROXY}"
}
```

.env

```
PROXY=http://localhost:3001
```

But it's not working in Reactjs, someone knows how to do that? I searched everywhere and nothing works. Thanks

Comment: Did you try the second method suggested by the documentation? This is the one we use in our team and it works very well: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually

Comment: Thanks for the advice, is that exactly what i'm looking for.